# Initializing to a dynamically allocated const char array from a const char array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, codeblocks

I am trying to write code that will assign a const char array to a dynamically allocated const char array. 
I tried to do it like

```
const char staticArray[4] = "abc";
const char * ptrDynamicArray;
ptrDynamicArray = new const char[4](staticArray);
```

But I get an error ("parenthesized initializer in array new [-fpermissive]").

I have two questions:

1. How could I solve it - like turn it off (I am using Code::Blocks 16.01)?
2. Can I initialize a dynamically allocated const char array somehow else?

Comment: First, prefer using `std::string`. to copy C-style strings, you need the services of `strcpy` or similar routines. Your expression, `new const char[4](staticArray);` tries to construct each of the elements in the newly created array with `staticArray`. And a `char` type cannot be constructed using a type of `char[4]`

Comment: Are the arrays supposed to be strings? Then why not use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)?

Comment: I need a const char* at the end, to pass it to fstream

Comment: You *do* know that streams can handle `std::string`? There are overloads of `<<` that takes `std::string` arguments. And if you use e.g. `read` or `write` to read or write raw data, then you can easily get a pointer to the contained data in the string object. This seems like [an XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), where you ask us with help for a solution to a problem you don't tell us about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot copy-initialize an array from another array directly, hence the error. You either need to manually copy the elements (or use `std::copy`), or, better, if you want a "copy"-able array use `std::array<char, 4>` instead.

But, as mentioned in the comments, the best probably is to use an [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) here, and use its [`std::string::c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) member function in case you need to pass around `const char*` pointers to old C-like interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Overloading new operator will do your job.

```
void * operator new[](size_t n, const char *s) {
    void *p = malloc(n);
    strcpy((char *)p, s);
    return p;
}
```

Now new operator can be called like :

```
const char staticArray[4] = "abc";
const char * ptrDynamicArray;
ptrDynamicArray = new (staticArray) char[4];
```